# How to hide a field in Adobe Acrobat Pro DC based on another fields content

Tags: adobe, conditional-formatting, acrobat

I want to hide a fields content based on whether a preceding field is empty or not.  How do I do that in Adobe Acrobat Pro DC version 19.008.20081.46137

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where "foo" is the name of the field that may be hidden, add the following to the custom Format script of the field that may or may not have a value.

```
if (event.target.value == "") {
    this.getField("foo").display = display.hidden;
}
else {
    this.getField("foo").display = display.visible;
}
```

[image]